# VBA - accessing variables from class 1 in class 2

Tags: vba

```
Elements class
Private m_length As Double
Private m_width As Double
Private m_thickness As Double
Private m_board As Boards     '--- Boards is object in class1
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set m_board = New Boards
End Sub

Boards class
Property Get Area()
Area=m_length*m_width
End Property
```

This is just an example.
I need the Boards object to have access to the Elements class. The Boards object is a member of the Elements class

```
Property Get Area()
Area=m_length*m_width
End Property
```

Comment: Is `Calss2` a typo only here or also in your code?

Comment: ok, I have class Elements with object Boards as class Boards
I want acces to value frm class Elements to calkulate som parametrs in object Boards

Comment: Despite the typo, `Set m_board = New Boards` does not match the type you declared earlier: `Private m_board As Calss2`.

Comment: ok, i corrected the code. but still , but still how do i get value in class Boards from Elements??

Comment: `Private` means they're inaccessible outside their own class. Declare it `Public` or create an accessor method. It looks to me like if a class has a method named `Area()` then the variables `m_length` and `m_width` belong in that class.

Comment: In VBA, properties are the way in which access is granted to private fields of a class.  The reason for using properties rather than making the class member fields public is so that the code in the Get/Set/Let methods can validate  the access or the returned value.  i.e. nobody can change the value of a private member without the class knowing that this has been done.

Comment: Please improve the question: 1. Replace the remaining `class1` and `class2` with the correct class names used in the rest of the code. 2. Try to better describe what your goal is. Do you want to access the parent object `Elements`  from within the `Board` object?

Comment: ok,  i corrected the question. I need acess in class Boards to Elements class variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code class `Elements` has a member of class `Boards`. If an instance of `Boards`, we name it **b**, wants to access data from an Elements object **e**, then **b** must have a reference to the specific `Elements` object that has **b** as its member. We must create a backlink. Create such reference by adding a member to `Boards`: `Private m_parent As Elements`

When an object of class `Elements` is initialized, set itself as the parent of the `m_boards` object:
`m_board.Parent = Me`

Now `m_board` can access its parent via `m_parent`.

##### Complete code

In addition to the above points you also need to create Properties.

`class module Boards`

```
' You need a reference to the parent
Private m_parent As Elements

' Allow class Elements to set the parent reference
Friend Property Let Parent(ByRef p As Elements)
  Set m_parent = p
End Property

Property Get Area()
  Area = m_parent.Length * m_parent.Width
End Property
```

`class module Elements`

```
Private m_length As Double
Private m_width As Double
Private m_thickness As Double
Private m_board As Boards
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set m_board = New Boards
        m_board.Parent = Me
End Sub

' Give Boards access to read lengt and width
Friend Property Get Length()
  Length = m_length
End Property

Friend Property Get Width()
  Width = m_width
End Property
```